# Load Parquet Files from ADLS Gen2 using ADF

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, parquet-dataset

I would like to setup ADF pipeline in such a way that I need to load all the Parquet files hosted for 2+ years on ADLS Gen2 with a hierarchy of Year -> Month -> Day -> Hour - > Min. Over the period, we did have some file structure changes with a variance of 2-3 columns. I would like to pull all the common columns and load entire data in a sql table. Can someone please point me to the resources which could help with my requirement.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure data factory pipeline,

1. Use the `Get Metadata` activity to get the list of parquet files.
2. Pass the child items to the `ForEach` activity to loop each current item.
3. Add the [If condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity) activity inside ForEach activity to check if the date from the file is greater than the current time minus 2.
4. Add a copy data activity in True activities to copy data from source to sink.

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-tool) to copy data to the SQL table.

Comment: thank you...will try this solution and share the outcome.

Comment: I am unable to get the child items recursively using 'Get Metadata'...any alternatives that I can explore...thank you!